# 'Unexpected end of record' on csv import using AngularJS ui grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, csv, angular-ui-grid

I've been trying to figure this out for some time now.  
I'm using angularjs ui grid, I'm also using Django. 
The following code is in the html:

```
<div ui-grid="gridOptions" class="grid" ui-grid-importer
    ui-grid-row-edit ui-grid-edit ui-grid-cellNav ui-grid-resize-columns
    ui-grid-auto-resize ui-grid-move-columns
    ui-grid-pagination ui-grid-exporter >
</div>
```

Notice ui-grid-importer.

I want to show the user and error when an import is attempted but does not succeed.  Such as a user tying to import something other than a CSV.
I'm getting the error:

```
uncaught exception: UNEXPECTED_END_OF_RECORD at char...
```

In the controller.js...
I've tried implementing within  $scope.gridOptions = {

```
importerErrorCallback: function( grid, errorKey, consoleMessage, context ) {
      console.log(errorKey);
      console.log(importer.invalidCsv);
      myUserDisplayRoutine( errorKey );
      myLoggingRoutine( consoleMessage, context );
      alert("in error callback")
 },
```

Before it ever reaches this code I get the unexpected_end_of_record error.

The docs link I've used:
http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.importer.api:GridOptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was not with angular ui grid.
Running program on Chrome gave a more clear error message:

```
Uncaught UNEXPECTED_END_OF_RECORD at char 2569:Experience\r        grunt-scripts-csv.js:329
```

The grunt file had this section on line 329:

```
CSV.error = function (err){
var msg = CSV.dump(err);
CSV.reset();
throw msg;};
```

Copying this to override it in a local js file and adding an alert message achieved my desired goal.